# R Data Aggregation With WHERE Clause on Group

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

As an example, I have the data.table shown below. I want to do a simple aggregation where b=sum(b). For c, however I want the value of the record in c where b is maximum. The desired output is shown below (data.aggr). This leads to a few questions:

1) Is there a way to do this data.table?

2) Is there a simpler way to do this in plyr?

3) In plyr the output object got change from a data.table to a data.frame. Can I avoid this behavior?

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table) 
dt <- data.table(a=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'), b=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                 c=c('m', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r'))
dt
#    a b c
# 1: a 1 m
# 2: a 2 n
# 3: a 3 p
# 4: b 4 q
# 5: b 5 r
dt.split <- split(dt, dt$a)
dt.aggr <- ldply(lapply(dt.split,  
    FUN=function(dt){ dt[, .(b=sum(b), c=dt[b==max(b), c]), 
    by=.(a)] }), .id='a')
dt.aggr
#   a b c
# 1 a 6 p
# 2 b 9 r
class(dt.aggr)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Comment: Why would you use `plyr` on a `data.table` :-O?

Comment: It's nice if you make your code copy-pastable -- that is, without the `>` or `+` at the start of each line.

Comment: Arun -- with David's solution I no longer need to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple operation within the `data.table` scope

```
dt[, .(b = sum(b), c = c[which.max(b)]), by = a]
#    a b c
# 1: a 6 p
# 2: b 9 r
```

A similar option would be

```
dt[order(b), .(b = sum(b), c = c[.N]), by = a]
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks David. Didn't know about which.max. Could you clarify the c=c[] notation? I don't see this in data.table documentation.

Comment: This is the ordinary sub-setting feature like you know from base R. `c[which.max(b)]` means "*the value of `c` where `b` is maximum*". `c = c[` means "*create a new column called `c` which will contain that value*"